# FastAPI does not replace "+" plus symbol in GET request

Tags: python, http, fastapi, urlencode, starlette

I understand this is not a FastAPI issue, but how to avoid this using FastAPI?

For example:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
async def root(q: str):
    return {"message": f"{q}"}
```

Issuing the following request:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=1+1
```

returns:

```
{"message":"1 1"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plus sign (`+`) has a semantic meaning in the query string, i.e., representing the space character. Similarly, the ampersand sign (`&`), which is used to separate the various `key=value` pairs in the query string.

When a request arrives, FastAPI processes the query parameters after decoding the URL, and hence, any `+` signs in the query string are decoded to a space. If you would like the `+` sign to be preserved, you should encode the query parameters in the URL before issuing the HTTP request, so that all `+` signs are converted to `%2B`. Then, when your FastAPI server decodes the query string, all `%2B` will be converted back to `+` signs.

In JavaScript, you can use the [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function, which takes as argument a complete URI:

```js
var encodedURL = encodeURI('http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=1+1');
```

or, use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function, which takes any object (such as string and number):

```js
var encodedURL =  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=' + encodeURIComponent('1+1');
```

If you are sending the request directly from the browser (i.e., by typing the URL in the address bar of the browser), then make sure to send it URL-encoded:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=1%2B1
```

If you still want to send the request in this format `http://127.0.0.1:8000/2?q=1+1`, and get back the response preserving the `+` signs, you can use `request.url.query`, which will return the raw query string, allowing you to split the `key=value` pairs and get the value of `q` parameter in the original form. Example:

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.get('/')
def root(request: Request):
    q = request.url.query.split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
    return {'message': q}
```

Answer (score 5):

`+` is a reserved character in URLs which is used to denotate whitespace (as your result indicates). URL-encode your values to avoid this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?q=1%2b1
```