# How to add routes to FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm working through tutorial on FastAPI

```
 from fastapi import FastAPI
 from typing import Optional
 app = FastAPI()
 
 @app.get("/")
 async def root():
     return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Result is expected:

```
{"message":"Hello World"}
```

But then tried to add another route:

```
@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: int, q:Optional[str] = None):
    return("item_id": item_id, "q":q)
```

Previous response. Why?

UPDATE:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return("Hello", "World")

@app.get("/items/{item_get}")
def read_item(item_id:  int, q: Optional[str]= None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q":q}
```

Response:

```
  127.0.0.1:51198 - "GET /items/5/q%3Dhello HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

Comment: That is unclear what the problem, what does "previous response" mean ? Did you get on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/12?q=test` ?

Comment: @azro
Your Question is not clear Bro

Comment: Looks like you might be trying with same url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, but as azro suggested you have to try with different URL

Comment: Try looking at [How to Use Dynamics Routes in FastAPI](https://www.slingacademy.com/article/how-to-use-dynamic-routes-in-fastapi/).

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427592/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74536449/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/17865804) on how to call an API endpoint that expects query parameters.

Comment: You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74136659/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815364/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying that you need q as query parameter as per the function definition
the path that you defined accepts `/items/{int}?q={str}`

but you seem to be fetching `http://127.0.0.1:51198/items/5/q=hello`

you have to replace the `/` before the `q` with `?`

the `?` in a url splits the path of the url, after the `?` symbol the content is called query parameters they are of the form `https://example.com/path?query_keyword=value` to add multiple parameters you use the `&` symbol like
`?param1=value1&param2=value`...

if you want to fetch the url you tried you can define another route like

```
@app.get("/items/{item_id}/{q:path}")
def read_item(item_id:  int, q: str= ""):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q":q}
```

but this is not suggested as handling more paths which you may define in future like

`/items/{item_id}/details`

`/items/{item_id}/warehouse`

will become complex so be careful when you use the `:path` specifier